# YII и работа модели Active Record

Tags: php, yii, база-данных

Я новичок в YII, и мне многие вещи кажутся непонятными.

Вот к примеру делаю я:

```
$x = AnyTable::model()->FindByPk(123);
```

$x->id , $x->text а так же $x->blob будут выводить что нужно.

Неужели FindByPk делает SELECT * FROM ... ?

Где можно конкретно прочитать про работы этих методов и где можно почитать про другие методы

К примеру не смогу найти метод который был бы аналогичен:

```
$sql = 'select user_id from users where user_name = :vasja ';
$sql = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql))
        return mysql_result($sql,0);
else
        return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.ar

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много.

```
$mod = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('d,status')
            ->from('cms_log')
            ->where(array('and', 'id_ct='.$_POST['ticket'],'uid='.$_POST['uid'] ))
            ->queryAll();
```

или так

```
$mod=LogUser::model()->findAll(array(
                                                'condition'=>'id_ct=:id_ct',
                                                'order'=>'d',
                                                'params'=>array(':id_ct'=>$_POST['ticket'],'uid'=>$_POST['uid']) 
                                            ));
```

а вообще в документации все подробно описано.